# How to unite a lot of data frames via a data frames' names in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have these two data frames (in real life I have 680):

```
DF1 <- data.frame(City = c("New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York"), Income = c("1","2","3","4","5"), Amount = c(0, 13291.23678, 0,0,0))
DF2 <- data.frame(City = c("Dallas", "Dallas","Dallas","Dallas","Dallas"), Income = c("1","2","3","4","5"),Amount = c(0, 65666.2885,106896.3682,69949.63342,35549.94405))
```

I must combine those two data frames via rows, but I have data frame' names in a list.

My expective outcome is to use that list to combine those data frames something like this:

```
DF<- data.frame(rbind(DFNames))
```

And generating this data frame:

```
       City Income    Amount
   New York      1      0.00
   New York      2  13291.24
   New York      3      0.00
   New York      4      0.00
   New York      5      0.00
     Dallas      1      0.00
     Dallas      2  65666.29
     Dallas      3 106896.37
     Dallas      4  69949.63
     Dallas      5  35549.94
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I have 680 data frames in real life and this method is a little bit delayed (I would have to paste 680 data frames' names). Greetings!

Comment: You also need to `unlist` `DFNames` first since `mget` expects a character vector. `do.call(rbind, mget(unlist(DFNames)))` works.

Comment: Doesn't directly answer the question, but do you really need/want to have 680 data frames in your environment? You'll probably have an easier time managing things if you have a list to hold all the data frames.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @camille, but you add anything for solution. Greetings!